# Phpmyadmin not working after upgrade to 22.04 and cannot be uninstalled

Tags: phpmyadmin, ubuntu-22.04

Upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 and upgraded php from 7.4 to 8.1. Phpmyadmin on localhost apache2 was working fine before (v5.0.3 from Oct 2020) but now I get a load of errors on the login page. eg:

```
Deprecation Notice in ./vendor/twig/twig/src/Loader/FilesystemLoader.php#40
 realpath(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($path) of type string is deprecated
```

which looks like its barfing at php8.1, and then if I try to login I get a page saying "The page not working right now"

When I run `sudo apt-get remove phpmyadmin` it reports "Package phpmyadmin is not installed, so not removed" which is unhelpful as it is still installed and exists in /usr/share/phpmyadmin and the apache2 config file is enabled.

So how does one remove it - will simply deleting the /usr/share/phpmyadmin folder and disabling the phpmyadmin.conf in apache2 to work, or will it leave other stuff behind in the mysql (mariabd) database that will mess up a re-install with the latest version?

Or can I simply install the latest version over the top of the existing 5.0.3?

And as a secondary question what has gone wrong here? - it seems that apt has forgotten it has phpmyadmin installed during the 20.04->22.04 update.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it turns out it is indeed that the old version of phpMyAdmin doesn't work with php8 :-(

First switch back to php7.4

```
sudo a2dismod php8.1
sudo a2enmod php7.4
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Now phpmyadmin5.0.2 works again
Then you can remove the old version and install the new one. First download it from the phpmyadmin website and extract it - say to `~/Downloads/phpMyAdmin-5.2.0-english/`

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/phpmyadmin/
sudo mkdir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/
sudo mv ~/Downloads/phpMyAdmin-5.2.0-english/* /usr/share/phpmyadmin/
sudo chown -R root:root /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

You'll probably have to also create a file `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/config.in.php`containing a 'secret' passphrase 32 chars long eg:

```
<?php
// use here a value of your choice 32 chars long or just copy this if you are on your own localhost
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '12345678901234567890123456789012';
$i=0;
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'cookie';
```

and you may also need to create a temp dir
`sudo mkdir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/tmp && sudo chmod 777 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/tmp`

and finally switch back to php8

```
sudo a2dismod php7.4
sudo a2enmod php8.1
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```